# Metro GridView Mouse Over Which Binding ItemID

Tags: c#, events, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I can easily get the itemID of a datasource from the object that is clicked with the below code. But can anyone please tell me how to get the same ItemID when I use the **Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)** event?

I'm trying to play a different sound when you mouse over different Gridview items. the sound filename comes from the datasource item

Thanks.

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId; 
        //Do something here with the DatasetItem[ItemID]
    }
```

OK I have tried this method

```
private async void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        String atext = "default";
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;

        if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
        {
            Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(null);

            TextBlock aTextBlock = Helpers.FindChild<TextBlock>(this, "aTittle");       
        }
```

The problem with this is the DataTemplate/Datagridview items all have the same name. As such the FindChild only returns the first item in the GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take point location from the event arguments (see the sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs.getcurrentpoint), then use VisualTreeHelper to check elements under the pointer

```
    void GridView_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gridView = sender as GridView;
        FrameworkElement root = Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement;

        Point position = gridView.TransformToVisual(root).TransformPoint(e.GetCurrentPoint(gridView).Position);


        // check items directly under the pointer
        foreach (var element in VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(position, root))
        {
            var context = ((FrameworkElement)element).DataContext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried the above but always seem to get Zero elements returned.

Comment: perhaps you get incorrect position. I updated the code sample in my answer. I tried it in my local application and it works for me. Gives the correct item. Note, the actual result depends on the control layout and pointer movements. For example, you can move mouse so, that PointerEnter is fired over the empty place, where there is no any items, just GridView ItemsPanel.